# Post no longer showing when hitting refresh with react/redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I am using react/redux/mongo/express/nodejs (stack) just in case that information helps. The problem is when I hit refresh my post seems to disappear. A user can click on the post from the list of post and it will show the post just fine, but when I hit refresh the post no longer shows up. I will post the code below to help.

EDIT: Here is server side code to show what I am making a call to on the back-end.

This sits on the router.js page:

```
app.get('/posts/:id', Posts.getOnePost);
```

---

This sits on the post controller page:

```
exports.getOnePost = function(req, res, next) {
  Posts.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundPost) {
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    } else {
      res.json(foundPost);
    }
  });
}
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from '../../actions/posts_actions';
import _ from 'lodash';

class ShowPosts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onDeleteClick = this.onDeleteClick.bind(this);
    this.deleteComment = this.deleteComment.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.getOnePost(id);
  }

  renderComments() {
    const { post } = this.props;

    return post.comments.map((comment) => {
      return (
        <li className="list-group-item" key={comment._id}>
          {comment.text}
          <button
            onClick={this.deleteComment, comment.id}
            className="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
            Delete
          </button>
          <Link
            to={`/posts/${post.id}/comments/${comment.id}/edit`}
            className="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
            Edit
          </Link>
        </li>
      );
    });
  }

  deleteComment(comment_id) {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.deleteComments(id, comment_id, () => {
      this.props.history.push(`/posts/${id}`);
    });
  }

  onDeleteClick() {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.deletePost(id, () => {
      this.props.history.push("/");
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { post } = this.props;

    if (!post) {
      return <div> Loading...No Post </div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Link className="btn btn-primary" to="/posts">Back To Post</Link>
        <button
          className="btn btn-danger pull-xs-right"
          onClick={this.onDeleteClick}
        >
          Delete Post
        </button>
        <Link
          className="btn btn-success pull-right"
          to={`/posts/${post.id}/edit`}>
            Edit Post
        </Link>
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
        <p>{post.content}</p>
        <ul className="list-group">
          {this.renderComments()}
        </ul>
        <Link
          className="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
          to={`/posts/${post.id}/comments/new`}>
            Comment
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ posts }, ownProps) {
  return { post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id] };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ShowPosts);
```

Here is the getOnePost actions:

```
export function getOnePost(id) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_POST,
          payload: response
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the reducer code?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where from id of post comes from. If it is part of state of react app, then it gets wiped out when you hit refresh. On refresh your javascript gets downloaded from server and starts afresh from clean state.

If id would be part of route, then your components would have a chance to recover it.

In your mapStateToProps, you state that post is something that you extract by index from posts part of the state. Upon refresh this posts part of the state is possibly empty.

Comment: the "id" is part of the route. The route looks like so localhost:8080/post/:id,
when the component mounts I can the getOnePost() passing in the id from the this.props.match.params.id. Does refresh not make componentDidMount() fire off?

Comment: Refresh completely wipes out your state and start your script from start.if component needs to be displayed, componentDidMount should be called. How about you try to ad some console logs to see what gets invoked and what is the id you are using on refresh

Comment: Are you using some authentication to get posts? If so authentication token would be lost on refresh if kept in state

Comment: When I hit refresh and if I log the this.props.match.params.id inside the componentDidMount I am getting the id for the correct post, but if I log this.props.post it is undefined after the refresh.  I will add the server side code in an edit to show you what I am making a call to.

Comment: It is likely that posts part of the state is empty after refresh, and that is where you get this.props.post

Comment: How do I make sure it isn't empty?

Comment: I firgued that componentDidMount() would be called on refresh and invoke getOnePost

Comment: Ho-hum. If it is empty fetch it.  Or rethink where and how are you fetching data from the server. Most likely posts get fetched when mount some component like list of posts. When you refresh on single post route component with all posts is not displayed, hence no posts. Maybe it makes sense to fetch all posts on script startup. Any how discussing possible reorganizatiins of your appmare way beyond scope of this question

Comment: But componentDidMount does not help since it is not fetching posts, and thet is where post property comes from

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147865/discussion-between-taylor-austin-and-davorin-rusevljan).